# public suffix list: why isn't wordpress.com listed there?

Tags: wordpress, network-programming, wordpress.com, public-suffix-list

sorry if this is a bit off-topic. I'm using `guava` which internally uses the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat). How come `blogspot.com` is there while `wordpress.com` isn't? (and also `etsy.com` and many others...)

I thought the purpose of this list is to help me detect that `ihadanny.wordpress.com` and `highlyscalable.wordpress.com` are not owned by the same person, while `www.outbrain.com` and `traffic.outbrain.com` are owned by the same person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is just because Wordpress hasn't submitted `wordpress.com` to the list as a public suffix.

Comment: ah, so the only way the list gets updated is if someone at wordpress submit it to mozilla? Isn't it a public knowledge project like wikipedia, where anyone can submit and moderators make sure its not spammed?

Comment: @ihadanny: That I don't know, but all the private/non-ICANN domains in the list have information on who submitted the domains to the list and the ones I looked at generally appeared to be from the company owning the domain.

Comment: "Requests for changes to the PRIVATE section must come from the domain owner."

Answer (score 1):

The list comes directly from Mozilla's PSL, and they depend on authoritative reports from registrars and site operators.